# How to max per column with nulls that should be replaced (with 0)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to get the MAX in the below dataframe?

```scala
val df_n = df.select($"ID").filter(($"READ") === "" && ($"ACT"!==""))
```

I have to find out the MAX of `ID` and in case if `ID` is `NULL`, I have to replace it with 0.

Comment: I tried withcolumn, but it is not working properly.

SELECT ISNULL((MAX(id),0) FROM DF WHERE READ='' AND act<>''

I am trying to achieve this sql query in Dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following?

### Test Dataset

```scala
scala> val df = Seq("0", null, "5", null, null, "-8").toDF("id")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)

scala> df.withColumn("idAsLong", $"id" cast "long").printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- idAsLong: long (nullable = true)


scala> val testDF = df.withColumn("idAsLong", $"id" cast "long")
testDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, idAsLong: bigint]

scala> testDF.show
+----+--------+
|  id|idAsLong|
+----+--------+
|   0|       0|
|null|    null|
|   5|       5|
|null|    null|
|null|    null|
|  -8|      -8|
+----+--------+
```

### Solution

```scala
scala> testDF.agg(max("idAsLong")).show
+-------------+
|max(idAsLong)|
+-------------+
|            5|
+-------------+
```

### Using na Operator

What if you had only negative values and `null` and so `null` is the maximum value? Use `na` operator on `Dataset`.

```scala
val withNulls = Seq("-1", "-5", null, null, "-333", null)
  .toDF("id")
  .withColumn("asInt", $"id" cast "int")  // <-- column of type int with nulls

scala> withNulls.na.fill(Map("asInt" -> 0)).agg(max("asInt")).show
+----------+
|max(asInt)|
+----------+
|         0|
+----------+
```

Without `na` and replacing `null` it simply won't work.

```scala
scala> withNulls.agg(max("asInt")).show
+----------+
|max(asInt)|
+----------+
|        -1|
+----------+
```

See [na: DataFrameNaFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@na:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the maximum ID in this dataframe, you just have to add

```
.agg(max($"ID"))
```

However, I do not understand why you would want to replace the maximum ID without further grouping by 0. Anyway, if you feel more comfortable with SQL, you can always use the SQL interface:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("DF")
spark.sql("select max(id) from DF").show
```

Comment: Scenario is possible of getting ID as NULL, if Max(ID) is NULL , I want to replace with 0. 

EX: SQL query
   'Select ISNULL(MAX(ID)) from DF'

Above same how can I achieve in DataFrame.