# How to prevent an aggregation function from ignoring NULL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Assume we have the following DataFrame in (Py)Spark. (I took the data from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705047/2205667).)

```
+----+--------+
|  id|idAsLong|
+----+--------+
|   0|       0|
|null|    null|
|   5|       5|
|null|    null|
|null|    null|
|  -8|      -8|
+----+--------+
```

**Question: How can I define/find a function `smax` which does not ignore `null`. That is, `.smax("isAsLong")` gives `null`.**

This question comes up when I am creating a pivot table. Namely

```
df.groupBy("id").pivot("var").max("val")
```

gives a table which is filled with 0, even though there is no value to compute.

Answer (score 0):

As null very big value can be used during max calculation:

```
val borderValue = Long.MaxValue

// null as border value
df.select(max(when(isnull($"idAsLong"), borderValue).otherwise($"idAsLong")).alias("res"))

  // back to null
  .withColumn("res", when($"res" === borderValue, null.asInstanceOf[Long]).otherwise($"res"))
```